# What does the "zone" stand for in proj?

Tags: coordinate-system, proj, pyproj, pyshp

I am using proj, in particular [pyproj](https://jswhit.github.io/pyproj/), to convert from UTM coordinates to the (x,y) coordinates used, for example, by Google Maps. There is a parameter called `zone` which I could not understand how I can determine. I have seen it varying across examples I looked up. What is the rule for specifying the `zone`?

By the way, the reason I need this transformation is because the points my `shp` are in this format once I use `pyshp` to access them.

Comment: It's a UTM zone, six degrees wide. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system. If the coordinate system of the shape is correctly defined pyproj only needs the 'to' coordinate system which for Google is Web Mercator EPSG:3857 http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/7483/ you can determine the correct zone from a geographic coordinate but not from an already projected coordinate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open up Google Earth.
2. Set the coordinate system to UTM (Tools>Options>3D View>Show Lat/Long)
3. Fly to your location
4. Down the bottom, the coordinates display the UTM zone plus the coordinates.

Eg South Australia is Zone 53
[image]

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system) describes the UTM zone system and gives global maps. There are formulae for converting between Lat/Long in degrees and UTM, including zone, if you need to do that, but they are quite involved (as you can see on the Wikipedia page) and already answered in other questions so I won't go into them here.